# how to get a json variable Whose value contains a "-"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, rectangles

i have a  json object  that contains :

```
                  {
                    "-database": "URL",
                    "-id": "Veveve",
                    "value": [
                        "*.serse.pl/*",
                        "*.qq.serser/*",

                        ]
                    }
```

my question is :
after Accepted the json at the Clint and saved my json object at my myjson Virabel 
how i set the **"-id"** value at ba-panel-title=""  ?

**when i do `myjson.-id`  i got  a 'undefined` parameter

Thank you

Comment: `-` is invalid syntax as prefix in object property. better use `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`myjson["-id"]`**

```
console.log(myjson["-id"]);
```

DEMO

```js
var myjson = {
  "-database": "URL",
  "-id": "Veveve",
  "value": [
    ".serse.pl/",
    ".qq.serser/"
  ]
};

console.log(myjson["-id"]);
```

Comment: ba-panel-title=" i["-id"] "   , it`s not working here thank you

Comment: @AhmadRweashd use different quotes `ba-panel-title="i['-id']"`

Comment: -Sajeetharan -Aleksey Solovey

Comment: @AhmadRweashd edit your question, to post the HTML section of the code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can pull **keys** and **values** from an object with `ng-repeat`. Here is a simple demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myjson = {
    "-database": "URL",
    "-id": "Veveve",
    "value": [
      ".serse.pl/",
      ".qq.serser/"
    ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in myjson">
    <div>KEY: {{key}} | VALUE: {{val}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example if you have an **array of objects**:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myjson = [{
    "-database": "URL",
    "-id": "Veveve",
    "value": [
      ".serse.pl/",
      ".qq.serser/"
    ]
  }, {
    "-database": "URL2",
    "-id": "Wiwiwi",
    "value": [
      ".qq.serser/"
    ]
  }, {
    "-database": "URL3",
    "-id": "Uauaua",
    "value": [
      ".serse.pl/"
    ]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in myjson">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in i">
      <div>KEY: {{key}} | VALUE: {{val}}</div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```